# Template not found for name [top_menu] and path [//_top_menu.gsp]

Tags: grails

I am working on grails app and rendering template in root gives an errors. Here are the steps taken:

1. I have a controller 'public' that has actions for each page do display...that includes 'home' my default page
2. I changed URL mapping(in UrlMappings.groovy) to point root to my default controller and action as following :
    "/"(controller: 'public', view: 'home')
3. Afterwards, pointing to the root 'app-name/', i got:

   Class: org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.taglib.exceptions.GrailsTagException
     Message: Template not found for name [top_menu] and path [//_top_menu.gsp]

I have template _top_menu.gsp in the view/public/ folder along the home.gsp

It works fine if i point to app-name/public/home, however, not when pointing to root. How come it does not render template in root?

Thank You for helping

p.s.
Grails 2.04. Windows 7

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The UrlMappings should be:

```
"/" ( controller:'public', action:'home' )
```

.. so no "view:'home'", but "action:'home'"

Comment: Ah! Thank you Tom for finding time to replay. It worked perfect